# Can you overload an attribute from a base class using @property decorators if the base class does not use them?

Tags: python, inheritance, properties, attributes, decorator

First consider something that works:

```
class Parrot:
    def __init__(self):
        self._voltage = 100000

    @property
    def voltage(self):
        print("Getting the current voltage.")
        return self._voltage


class NorwegianBlue(Parrot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._voltage = self._voltage + 99999

    @property
    def voltage(self):
        print("Getting the current voltage.")
        return self._voltage
```

Output:

```
>>> print(Parrot().voltage)
Getting the current voltage.
100000
>>> print(NorwegianBlue().voltage)
Getting the current voltage.
199999
```

But what if the base class does not use decorators?  Can you inherit the attribute and still use decorators?  Obviously, this doesn't work:

```
class Parrot2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.voltage = 100000

class NorwegianBlue(Parrot2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._voltage = self.voltage + 99999

    @property
    def voltage(self):
        print("Getting the current voltage.")
        return self._voltage
```

Output:

```
>>> Parrot2().voltage
100000
>>> NorwegianBlue().voltage
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-88540467e120> in <module>()
----> 1 NorwegianBlue().voltage

<ipython-input-51-22a74bbd6701> in __init__(self)
      1 class NorwegianBlue(Parrot2):
      2     def __init__(self):
----> 3         super().__init__()
      4         print(self.voltage)
      5         self._voltage = self.voltage + 900000

<ipython-input-32-8e868761451b> in __init__(self)
      1 class Parrot2:
      2     def __init__(self):
----> 3         self.voltage = 100000

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: You could if it were writable, but the readonly attribute conflicts with the superclass init.

Comment: Thanks. So presumably best to avoid property decorators altogether if the base class is not using them? (I am not the author of the base class)

Comment: No, just best not to change the *interface* of the base class.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what changing the interface means.  Would you mind demonstrating how I do this as an answer?

Comment: @Bill Think of the interface as a contract provided by the `Parrot2` class: any instance of `Parrot2` will have an instance attribute named `voltage`. The subclass you define, however, *shadows* that attribute with a property (think of a property as a special kind of class attribute), preventing anyone (*including* `Parrot2.__init__`) from reading or writing the instance attribute `Parrot2` promised to make available.

Comment: Oh.  So, is the problem here simply that I haven't provided a setter method for the property in my subclass?

Comment: Adding `@voltage.setter` works.  shall I demonstrate the correct answer or would you like to?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible.  As pointed out in the comments above, the exception was due to the property not being writable due to the absence of a setter method.  This meant that `Parrot2.__init__` could not initialize the attribute.

The following works:

```
class Parrot2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.voltage = 100000

class NorwegianBlue(Parrot2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._voltage = self.voltage + 99999

    @property
    def voltage(self):
        print("Getting the current voltage.")
        return self._voltage

    @voltage.setter
    def voltage(self, value):
        print("Setting the current voltage.")
        self._voltage = value
```

Output:

```
>>> Parrot2().voltage
100000
>>> NorwegianBlue().voltage
Setting the current voltage.
Getting the current voltage.
Getting the current voltage.
199999
```

Thanks.